# Checking for the return type of predicate

Tags: javascript

```js
Array.prototype.takeWhile = function (predicate) {
    'use strict';
    var $self = this
    if (typeof predicate === 'function') {
        let flagged = false, matching_count = 0, nomatching_count = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < $self.length; i++) {
            let e = $self[i]
            if (predicate(e)) {
                if (!nomatching_count) {
                    matching_count++
                } else {
                    flagged = true
                    break
                }
            } else {
                nomatching_count++
            }
        }
        return !flagged ? $self.slice(0, matching_count) : $self
    }
    throw new TypeError('predicate must be a function')
};

var test = function () {
  var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  alert(array.takeWhile(x => x <= 3))
};
```

```html
<button onclick="test()">Click me</button>
```

After the condition:

```
if (typeof predicate === 'function') {

}
```

I want to ask: how to check the return type of `predicate`?

I want to prevent this case:

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
alert(array.takeWhile(function () {}));
```

Comment: Not sure this is possible. A JavaScript function could return a number on one invocation, and a string on another invocation.

Comment: Why do you need to prevent this? Other array methods don't have any sort of check for this.

Comment: @Soviut The message says: `predicate must be a function` while `function () {}` is a function without any return type.

Comment: It does have a return type, it returns "undefined". However, you can't check this until you run the function. There is no static analysis on this since Javascript is a dynamic language and a function can return many different types depending on input.

Comment: Also, couldn't you just use `Array.filter()` for this? `[1,2,3].filter(x => x <= 3)` ?

Comment: If you want it to break early, you could also use `Array.some()`

Comment: Where/how are you learning, JavaScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript functions can return anything so there's no way of predicting or inferring their return type. The only way to determine the type of what's been returned is to run the function and check the type of the result.

```
var result = predicate(e);
if (typeof result === 'undefined') {
    throw 'Invalid predicate'
}
```

Notice that the return type of a function can be `undefined`, which is what an empty function will return.

However, this seems unnecessary since built in array methods don't have any check for this sort of edge case. For example `[1,2,3].filter(function() {});` the `Array.filter()` method returns an empty array because the supplied function (predicate) never returns true against any items in the array.

```js
console.log( [1,2,3].filter(function() {}) );
```

Comment: I'm sorry. You mean that: some invalid case could be ignored because it's no need (or unnecessary) to check, don't you? Hmm.... So, What's it automatically? What's not?

Comment: Yes, the predicate will always return a result even if it's an empty function and `undefined` is considered "falsey" like `false` and `null`. So if the result of calling the predicate is falsey then just move on.